# Route virtual file and virtual directory to a single file

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to route an virtual file `data-protection.html` and an virtual directory `/content_media/data_protection/` to an actual file `/var/www/html/media/data_protection/data-protection_2023_01.html` through nginx.

That's my current solution, which works partly:

```
location ~* /data-protection.html  {
  alias /var/www/html/media/data_protection/;
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /content_media/data_protection/data-protection_2023_01.html;
}

location /content_media/data_protection {
  alias /var/www/html/media/data_protection/;
  index data-protection_2023_01;
}
```

When calling `example.com/content_media/data_protection/data-protection.html` it works fine. But, when I call `example.com/data-protection.html` the style.css laying in the same directory `/var/www/html/media/data_protection/style.css` cannot be found.

Can someone help me, with this (most probably easy solvable) problem?
Thanks in advance!